# Removing the WordPress.com ribbon

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, hosting, headers

This is such a simple question, but I'm having trouble getting the answer.  Is it possible to have a blog at WordPress.com and not have the WordPress.com banner (shown below)?  Is it simply a matter of purchasing the ["master of your domain" premium feature](http://en.wordpress.com/products/)?  Or must I host my own WordPress.org installation (which is not a big deal)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ribbon is merely a way to quickly administer your site.  It's actually there for self-hosted WordPress.org setups, too (though you can turn it off with a filter).

But think for a few minutes about *why* you want it hidden.

- Do you want it hidden from just you because you don't need it?
- Do you want it hidden from you readers so they aren't reminded you're hosted by WordPress.com?
- Does it not fit with the aesthetic of your site?

If you want to hide it from your readers, keep in mind that "[The only people who can see it are those who also have WordPress.com blogs and are logged into WordPress.com when they visit your blog.](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/how-to-remove-the-admin-bar?replies=19)"

If you want it hidden from just you or if it doesn't really fit with your site, you would be best suited migrating to a self-hosted installation.  You can get on a shared host for about $6/month and can get a custom domain for about $8/year depending on the host.  Migrating is pretty easy, and then you'd have full control over the presentation of your site without needing to buy other premium add-ons.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  Regarding the "why" - yes, for all of those reasons.  As you say, it is reasonably straightforward to get a WordPress installation on a shared host.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking a simple, inexpensive "premium" feature at wordpress.com